# Customizing UserAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I'm trying to customize the UserAdmin like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


admin.site.unregister(User)

class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('groups',)
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'last_login')


admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

however after doing this and testing on the admin site the changes aren't reflected.

If I remove the last line:

```
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

it throws an error saying that User isn't registered so i think it's recognizing the new admin just not taking any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's a case, but maybe you should inherit from `from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin` and not from the ModelAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to just override the built-in UserAdmin, changing what you need:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.unregister(User)

UserAdmin.filter_horizontal = ('groups',)
UserAdmin.list_display = ('username', 'email', 'last_login')

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```